# Como pasar el valor de un botón a un input ?Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero pasar el valor de un botón a un input pero no he podido, estoy aprendiendo. He buscado información pero no la encuentro.

```
<button type="button" id="boton" value="7">7</button>

<input type="text"  id="resultado">
```

```
  var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');


    boton.onclick = function(e){
      resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent  + "7";
 }
```

(Literal) Pasar ese 7 al input.

[image]
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siendo que es un `input`, tienes que invocar la propiedad `value` para asignar el valor, no `textContent`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
 var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    boton.onclick = function(e){
      resultado.value +=  this.value;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="boton" value="7">7</button>

<input type="text"  id="resultado">
```

Si quieres reemplazar sin añadir cada vez el valor:

```js
 var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    boton.onclick = function(e){
      resultado.value =  this.value;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="boton" value="7">7</button>

<input type="text"  id="resultado">
```

> ### Dos mejoras al código
>
> - Nótese que en ambos casos he usado `this` para obtener el valor que tenga el botón.
> - En Javascript, si quieres concatenar, puedes usar simplemente `elValor += elNuevoValor`, en lugar de `elValor = elValor + elNuevoValor`

---

### El caso de `textContent`

`textContent` funcionaría en el caso de un contenedor, como `div`, `p` etc.

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
var mTotal=0;

    boton.onclick = function(e){
      mTotal += parseInt(this.value);
      resultado.textContent = mTotal;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="boton" value="7">7</button>

<p>Hola soy p. Total de 7 en 7: [<span id="resultado"></span>]</p>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono en un compilador, que es donde hago pruebas. pero al momento de intentar con un navegador me da este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: @MiguelPatiño *`'onclick' of null`* parece indicar que el elemento al que quieres asignar ese evento es nulo en el contexto. Revisa si antes tienes la referencia (al botón supongo) y si el mismo se encuentra en el documento.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió bastante, pero ahora como hago para que cada vez que de click en el botón se vaya sumando el 7? (7+7+7+7) cada vez que se presiona se suma otro 7
Gracias!

Comment: @HugoGonzález en el último bloque de código te he puesto un ejemplo donde se va acumulando de 7 en 7. En ese ejemplo se toma el `value` del botón como parámetro de incremento.